# I need help for Auto-Detect language already installed on my website

Tags: php, mysql

Hello new staff here and the bad English, but I really need some help!

I have a site that already has some languages​​, the [mytrip.gallery](http://www.mytrip.gallery/), but it does not auto-detect the language automatically and was wondering if anyone knows how to do this, can someone help me? I will spend some code pages:

**in INCLUDE/CONFIG:**

```
`<?
$config = array();

// Begin Configuration
$config['basedir']     =  '---';
$config['baseurl']     =  '---';

$DBTYPE = '----';
$DBHOST = '----';
$DBUSER = '----';
$DBPASSWORD = '---';
$DBNAME = '---';

$default_language = "english"; //Valid options are english, french, spanish, portuguese, japanese, chinese_simplified or chinese_traditional
// End Configuration

session_start();
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$config['adminurl']      =  $config['baseurl'].'/administrator';
$config['cssurl']      =  $config['baseurl'].'/css';
$config['imagedir']      =  $config['basedir'].'/img';
$config['imageurl']      =  $config['baseurl'].'/img';
$config['pdir']      =  $config['basedir'].'/pics';
$config['purl']      =  $config['baseurl'].'/pics';
$config['mdir']      =  $config['basedir'].'/mpics';
$config['murl']      =  $config['baseurl'].'/mpics';
echo file_get_contents($config['baseurl']."/startup.php");
require_once($config['basedir'].'/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php');
require_once($config['basedir'].'/libraries/mysmarty.class.php');
require_once($config['basedir'].'/libraries/SConfig.php');
require_once($config['basedir'].'/libraries/SError.php');
require_once($config['basedir'].'/libraries/adodb/adodb.inc.php');
require_once($config['basedir'].'/libraries/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
require_once($config['basedir'].'/libraries/SEmail.php');

function strip_mq_gpc($arg)
{
    $arg = str_replace('"',"'",$arg);
    $arg = stripslashes($arg);
    return $arg;
}

$conn = &ADONewConnection($DBTYPE);
$conn->PConnect($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASSWORD, $DBNAME);
@mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
$sql = "SELECT * from config";
$rsc = $conn->Execute($sql);

if($rsc){while(!$rsc->EOF)
{
$field = $rsc->fields['setting'];
$config[$field] = $rsc->fields['value'];
STemplate::assign($field, strip_mq_gpc($config[$field]));
@$rsc->MoveNext();
}}

if ($_REQUEST['language'] != "")
{
    if ($_REQUEST['language'] == "english")
    {
        $_SESSION['language'] = "english";
    }
    elseif ($_REQUEST['language'] == "french")
    {
        $_SESSION['language'] = "french";
    }
    elseif ($_REQUEST['language'] == "spanish")
    {
    $_SESSION['language'] = "spanish";
}
elseif ($_REQUEST['language'] == "portuguese")
{
    $_SESSION['language'] = "portuguese";
}
elseif ($_REQUEST['language'] == "japanese")
{
    $_SESSION['language'] = "japanese";
}
elseif ($_REQUEST['language'] == "chinese_simplified")
{
    $_SESSION['language'] = "chinese_simplified";
}
elseif ($_REQUEST['language'] == "chinese_traditional")
{
    $_SESSION['language'] = "chinese_traditional";
}
}

if ($_SESSION['language'] == "")
{
$_SESSION['language'] = $default_language;
}

if ($_SESSION['language'] == "english")
{
include("lang/english.php");
}
elseif ($_SESSION['language'] == "french")
{
include("lang/french.php");
}
elseif ($_SESSION['language'] == "spanish")
{
include("lang/spanish.php");
}
elseif ($_SESSION['language'] == "portuguese")
{
include("lang/portuguese.php");
}
elseif ($_SESSION['language'] == "japanese")
{
include("lang/japanese.php");
}
elseif ($_SESSION['language'] == "chinese_simplified")
{
include("lang/chinese_simplified.php");
}
elseif ($_SESSION['language'] == "chinese_traditional")
{
include("lang/chinese_traditional.php");
}
else
{
include("lang/".$default_language.".php");
}

for ($i=0; $i<count($lang); $i++)
{
STemplate::assign('lang'.$i, $lang[$i]);
}
if($config['re_mobile'] == "1" && $config['m_url'] != "")
{
if($mobile != "1")
{
    include("mobile.php");
    $mcheck = is_md();
    if($mcheck != "")
    {
        header("Location:".$config['m_url']);exit;
    }
}
}
STemplate::assign('baseurl',       $config['baseurl']);
STemplate::assign('basedir',       $config['basedir']);
STemplate::assign('adminurl',       $config['adminurl']);
STemplate::assign('cssurl',       $config['cssurl']);
STemplate::assign('imagedir',        $config['imagedir']);
STemplate::assign('imageurl',        $config['imageurl']);
STemplate::assign('pdir',        $config['pdir']);
STemplate::assign('purl',        $config['purl']);
STemplate::assign('mdir',        $config['mdir']);
STemplate::assign('murl',        $config['murl']);
STemplate::setCompileDir($config['basedir']."/temporary");
STemplate::setTplDir($config['basedir']."/themes");
```

### ...

**and has folders with languages ​​in include / language, see an example of English:**

```
<?
$lang = array();

$lang['0'] =  "Login";
$lang['1'] =  "Home";
$lang['2'] =  "Not a member yet?";
$lang['3'] =  "Get an invitation and register.";
$lang['4'] =  "Receive an invitation";
$lang['5'] =  "Login using your facebook account.";
$lang['6'] =  "Connect using Facebook";
```

### $lang['7'] =  "Login using your e-mail address.";`

It also has Portuguese, Spanish, Japanese

I appreciate any help, I know it can be easy for some exeprientes programmers and for this I am asking for help!

I FOUND ON MENU_MENU.TPL

```
<div class="nav sysOutLink"><a href="javascript:void(0)"      {literal}onclick="App.ajaxDialog('{/literal}{$baseurl}{literal}/language.php', {id:     'sysLangPopup', width: '550px'})"{/literal}>{if $smarty.session.language eq "english"}English{elseif $smarty.session.language eq "spanish"}Español{elseif $smarty.session.language eq "french"}Français{elseif $smarty.session.language eq "portuguese"}Português{elseif $smarty.session.language eq "japanese"}日本の{elseif $smarty.session.language eq "chinese_simplified"}中文（简体）{elseif $smarty.session.language eq "chinese_traditional"}中國傳統文化{/if}</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on browser language, use:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
```

Comment: okay, I understand, but how to include this in the above code and link to portuguese.php for example, each language?

Comment: Have you included the above variable in your code and seen what it outputs? You need to do this work for yourself, we are not here to do everything and your code looks reasonable above beginner to understand. I have given you the lead. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php. Consider a switch/case though :)